# Mirrored object not symmetrical

Tags: mirror

I am trying to mirror an object and the original is symmetrical along all axis, but when I attempt to mirror across the y axis, the mirrored side is tilted to a different angle.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Mirror modifier mirrors the object in its local space. If the object is rotated its local axes differ from the scene's global axes. If you have an object and want to make its local rotation match the scene you need to apply rotation by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> -> Rotation:

[image]