# Why mirror not perfect align

Tags: modifiers

Why flip mirror or mirror modifier not working perfect. I applied rotation and scale. With the mesh selected i duplicated with Alt+D and flip with 3d cursor at center Ctrl+M and X axis. I tried with the mirror modifier same result. Any suggestion or help. Why its not perfect mirror to other side. Thanks

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51868

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/mirrored-object-not-symmetrical and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rest of the model is not on the center. As you can see, the red line misses the origin
[image]
You need to align the model again, or just create some empty, that will serve as new center

Comment: The user is talking about applying the modifier in reference to the 3d cursor, but I have used the Mirror modifier for some time and wasn't aware that the 3d cursor could be used with it? Isn't it in reference to the object's Origin? I would always snap the Origin to the Cursor (if I needed to move the Origin) before I apply the modifier. Please let me know if I am mistaken and the 3d cursor can be used (which would be weird since it is moved all the time).

Comment: @hatinacat2000 They didn't use the 3D cursor with the mirror modifier (you can't), they used it with Ctrl+M, the *Interactive Mirror* tool.